Difficulty understanding proof that the Topologist's Sine Curve is not path-connected.
I'm reading Hatcher's Introduction to Point-set Topology (https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Top/TopNotes.pdf)
The Topologist's Sine Curve is given as an example on page 20, as follows:

Example. Let $X$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is the closure of the graph of the function $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ for $x > 0$. Thus $X$ consists of this graph together with the line segment $A$ in the $y$-axis from $(0, -1)$ to $(0, 1)$. Let $B$ denote the graph of $f$ itself, so $X$ is the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$. Obviously $A$ and $B$ are both path-connected. We will show that $X$ itself is not path-connected, hence $A$ and $B$ are the two path components of $X$.
Let $f : [0,1] \rightarrow X$ be a path starting at a point in $A$. We know that $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed since $A$ is closed. We will show that $f^{-1}(A)$ is also open. This implies $f^{-1}(A) = [0, 1]$ since $[0, 1]$ is connected and $f^{-1}(A)$ is nonempty. The equation $f^{-1}(A) = [0, 1]$ says that $f([0, 1]) \subset A$, and thus there is no path in $X$ joining a point in $A$ to a point in $B$. To show that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open let $t_0$ be any point in $f^{-1}(A)$. Choose a small open disk $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at $f(t_0)$. Then $D \cap X$ has infinitely many path-components, one of which is $D \cap A$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(D)$ is an open set in $[0, 1]$ containing $t_0$, so there is an interval $I \subset [0, 1]$ which is open in $[0, 1]$, contains $t_0$, and is contained in $f^{-1}(D)$. This interval is path-connected, so its image $f(I)$ is also path-connected and therefore lies inside one of the path components of $D \cap X$. This path component contains the point $f(t_0) \in A$ so it has to be the path component $D \cap A$. This says that $f(I) \subset A$, or in other words $I \subset f^{-1}(A)$. Thus $f^{-1}(A)$ contains a neighborhood of $t_0$ in $[0, 1]$. Since $t_0$ was an arbitrary point of $f^{-1}(A)$ we conclude that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $[0, 1]$, finishing the argument.

I don't understand the logic in the bolded section. Why is that we can conclude that $f^{-1}(A)=[0, 1]$ if $f^{-1}(A)$ is open?

Conected spaces have no clopen (i.e. open and closed) sets other than the empty set and the whole space.

I had forgotten that property, thank you.
